# How to give access to columns to new user when current user does not see the tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Using SYSTEM user I create a new user. After that I try to give this user access to specific columns only in 1 table, but get the error that this table does not exist. Meaning that SYSTEM user does not have access to this table. Unfortunately, the user that has access to the normal production tables cannot manage user privileges and access. What are my options?

```
CREATE USER test1 IDENTIFIED BY 123456;
GRANT UPDATE (extinvno, invoiceno) ON invoice TO test1;
```

Edit: Solution
Created 3 views that I needed. GRANT-ed the new user SELECT and UPDATE on 2 of the views and SELET on the 3rd. For the new user I had to use the chema to refer to the views: chema.view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SYSTEM` doesn't own the table then you need to specify who does; for example if the table was in the HR schema you would do:

```
GRANT UPDATE (extinvno, invoiceno) ON HR.invoice TO test1;
```

... using the real owning schema name, of course.

It isn't that `SYSTEM` doesn't have access to the table; it's that by default it's looking for `SYSTEM.invoice`, which doesn't exist.

The table owner could also grant the update privilege to `test1`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was it. May I ask another question? I just added INSERT and UPDATE  for said table, but when connecting with the user there are is no table Invoices. Am I missing something?

Comment: By default `test1` will also have to prefix the table name with its owner. (You can create a synonym, or change the session's `current_schema`, but that's going further from the question...) If you're expecting to see it in, for example, SQL Developer's 'Tables' list under the connection, it won't appear there; you'd need to expand 'Other Users' and then the owner and its 'Tables' list.

Comment: I see. I got to access the table with schema.table. But, I get to see everything. I think I have given the wrong SELECT premission:
`GRANT SELECT ON sol.invoice TO test1;`

With this I see all columns. Not just `extinvno` and `invoiceno`. But adding them to the script returns an error.

Comment: You can't restrict the visible columns like that. The usual way to do that sort of thing is by creating a view on top of the table which just exposes specific columns, possibly with [an instead-of trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-9F06D45C-7C60-434E-A597-114A0C445671__CIHFGDJG) to handle DML operations, and then only grant privileges on the view - *not* on the underlying table.

Comment: A more sophisticated approach is [virtual private database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html) - but again that's getting way beyond your question.